# @ManyToOne Referencing a composite key in JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have following entities

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(SubjectId.class)
class Subject {
    @Id
    String name;
    @Id
    String volume;
    ........
}

class SubjectId {
    String name;
    String volume;
    //constructor, getters and setters
    ..........
}

@Entity
class Student {
    @Id
    String studentId;

    String subject;

    String subjectVolume;
}
```

I want to map the fields **subject** and **subjectVolume** of class `Student` to composite primary key of class `Subject` as a `@ManyToOne` relationship. But I don't know what should I pass inside `@ManyToOne`(?).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**Edit:**

I want to use the columns `subjectName` and `subjectVolume` as entity fields in class Student as well. I don't want to do `student.getSubject().getSubjectName()` instead I want `student.getSubjectName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just declare the relation this way (instead of declaring the fk fields):

```
class Student{
    @Id
    String studentId;

    @ManyToOne // this is sufficient create foreign-key columns in the Student-table
    Subject subject;
}
```

The generated columns of the Student table will have these names by default:
[image]

In case you need different column names you should look for the `@JoinColumn` annotation.

---

edit: to be able to directly call `student.getSubjectName()` you could still decide to include single parts of the composite foreign key additionally as entity properties, in this case you need to make sure to declare the second (duplicate) column mapping with `insertable=false` and `updatable=false`, since its value is already managed by the `@ManyToOne` fk:

```
    @Entity
    static class Student {
        @Id
        String studentId;

        @ManyToOne
        Subject subject;

        @Column(name = "subject_name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        String subjectName;
    }
```

However, I'd probably prefer simply declaring a custom `getSubjectName()` getter which just returns `subject.getName()`.

Comment: What if I want to use the columns subjectName and subjectVolume as entity fields in class Student as well? I don't want to do student.getSubject().getSubjectName() instead I want just student.getSubjectName(). Is that possible?

Comment: please check the updated part of the answer